# Cannot Resolve Method 'newDataOutputStream'

Tags: java, android

I am getting an cannot resolve method error when i do this:

```
DataOutputStream os = newDataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
```

My imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.text.format.Formatter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
```

Code for class

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    class sentMessage implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Socket client = serverSocket.accept();
                DataOutputStream os = newDataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                str = smessage.getText().toString();
                msg = msg + "\n Server : " + str;

                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        chat.setText(msg);
                    }
                });
                os.writeBytes(str);
                os.flush();
                os.close();
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a space.

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
                         ^
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir @chunjef it was a really silly mistake haha. I was stuck at it for hours.